# Get the sixth matching line in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
GeraLinha('1', '            860,96 ', 1'18/11/2010', '0237.02912.1999.0022512 ');
GeraLinha('1', '          1.858,60 ', '17/11/2010', '0237.02911.1999.0033109 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            397,76 ', '17/11/2010', '0237.02911.1999.0032989 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            300,62 ', '17/11/2010', '0237.02911.1999.0032898 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            915,95 ', '12/11/2010', '0422.02896.1999.0000277 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            549,30 ', '18/11/2010', '0237.02912.1999.0059833 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            861,88 ', '24/11/2010', '0237.02916.1999.0000134 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            936,62 ', '19/11/2010', '0356.02703.1999.0072998 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            384,15 ', '18/11/2010', '0033.02907.1999.0004992 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            958,82 ', '17/11/2010', '0237.02911.1999.0032926 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            766,86 ', '22/11/2010', '0341.02922.1999.0000166 ');
GeraLinha('1', '            300,26 ', '17/11/2010', '0237.02911.1999.0033505 ');
```

I'm using the following regex to match this group, but I just want the sixth line. Is it possible to define in the regex "I want the sixth match"? If it's not possible *at all*, is there is any other way to achieve the desired result?

http://regexr.com/3cas9

As you can see here, I'm matching all.

```
/GeraLinha\((.*)\);/g
```

Comment: Do you need to match just `GeraLinha('1', '            549,30 ', '18/11/2010', '0237.02912.1999.0059833 ');`?

Comment: Why not just split on newlines and take the 6th line?

Comment: "i just want the 6 value", what do you mean? Give a concrete example.

Comment: Without the other peoples comments and stribizhev's answer, I would have interpreted this as _get the sixth "field" from each line_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match all 6 lines at once.
The 6th line contents (using your regex) is in capture group 1.

*This works because each iteration of the quantified group `{6}`

capture buffer 1 is overwritten, leaving the 6th line of data only.*

For continuous lines:

`text.match(/(?:^GeraLinha\((.*)\);\s*){6}/m);`

For non-continuous lines:

`text.match(/(?:^GeraLinha\((.*)\);\s*(?:(?!^GeraLinha\(.*\);\s*)^.*\s*)*){6}/m);`

Formatted:

```
 (?:
      ^ GeraLinha\(
      ( .* )                        # (1)
      \); \s* 
      (?:
           (?! ^ GeraLinha\( .* \); \s* )
           ^ .* \s* 
      )*
 ){6}
```

Comment: Wow.. i'm bit confuse with your regex.. but it's perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can match 5 lines starting with `GeraLinha(` and then match and *capture* the 6th:

```
(?:GeraLinha\(.*\r?\n){5}(GeraLinha\(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ7fL6/1)

Here, `(?:GeraLinha\(.*\r?\n){5}` subpattern matches the 5 lines due to the `{5}` [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). Then, we just match and capture the next line that is the 6th one.

```js
var re = /(?:GeraLinha.*\r?\n){5}(GeraLinha.*)/; 
var str = 'GeraLinha(\'1\', \'            860,96 \', 1\'18/11/2010\', \'0237.02912.1999.0022512 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'          1.858,60 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0033109 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            397,76 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0032989 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            300,62 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0032898 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            915,95 \', \'12/11/2010\', \'0422.02896.1999.0000277 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            549,30 \', \'18/11/2010\', \'0237.02912.1999.0059833 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            861,88 \', \'24/11/2010\', \'0237.02916.1999.0000134 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            936,62 \', \'19/11/2010\', \'0356.02703.1999.0072998 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            384,15 \', \'18/11/2010\', \'0033.02907.1999.0004992 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            958,82 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0032926 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            766,86 \', \'22/11/2010\', \'0341.02922.1999.0000166 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            300,26 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0033505 \');';
var m = str.match(re);
if (m !== null) {
    document.write(m[1]);
}
```

If you can consider an almost non-regex approach, you can split the lines and just get the one with Index 5 (I am using `/\r?\n+/` regex to match line breaks to support both Unix and Windows OS newline styles):

```js
var str = 'GeraLinha(\'1\', \'            860,96 \', 1\'18/11/2010\', \'0237.02912.1999.0022512 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'          1.858,60 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0033109 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            397,76 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0032989 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            300,62 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0032898 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            915,95 \', \'12/11/2010\', \'0422.02896.1999.0000277 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            549,30 \', \'18/11/2010\', \'0237.02912.1999.0059833 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            861,88 \', \'24/11/2010\', \'0237.02916.1999.0000134 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            936,62 \', \'19/11/2010\', \'0356.02703.1999.0072998 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            384,15 \', \'18/11/2010\', \'0033.02907.1999.0004992 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            958,82 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0032926 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            766,86 \', \'22/11/2010\', \'0341.02922.1999.0000166 \');\nGeraLinha(\'1\', \'            300,26 \', \'17/11/2010\', \'0237.02911.1999.0033505 \');';

var lines = str.split(/\r?\n+/);
if (lines !== null && lines.length>5) {
   document.write(lines[5]);
  }
```